# FastAPI, SQLAlchemy - Is there a need for Pydantic with GET only API

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm designing an API using FastAPI + SQLAlchemy to connect to a postgres backend. This API will have only GET endpoints, i.e. there is no requirement to write data back into the database.

I've been reading through the (very nice) FastAPI docs, specifically the [relational db section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#sql-relational-databases). The examples all use both `sqlalchemy` models and `pydantic` for data modelling. However as best I can see `pydantic` is only required for POST requests.

I'm trying to work out if there's a use case for adopting `pydantic` for an API with only GET endpoints? Or can I simplify things by just using `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: Pydantic is used to define the response model for those GET-requests (if you're returning JSON); if you're just rendering templates, pydantic isn't really used. However, if you're returning JSON, Pydantic is very useful to define exactly which fields and their values are included in the response. You can configure `from_attributes` on those models to make Pydayntic automagically load values from SQLAlchemy objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FastAPI doesn't need Pydantic at all in any facet of its functionality!

**BUT**

You have to consider what you are getting from using Pydantic:

1. **Schema validation during I/O through the API.**

   You don't need to validate the input (and output) manually with logic, but instead, Pydantic does that for you, provided that you have defined the models accordingly
2. **Schema definition in Swagger.**

   If you have provided Pydantic models in the endpoint definitions, FastAPI swagger automatically peaks on those and presents the appropriate definitions for each endpoint.

So in your case, you don't specifically need Pydantic, but you should consider what you may be losing by not defining the output models!

Hope this helped to clarify the subject :)

*As a side note, consider what @MatsLindh refers to in the comment and set [`from_attributes = True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#arbitrary-class-instances) to avoid some of the hustle of keeping fields in sync between SQLAlchemy ORM models and Pydantic ones.*

Comment: Thanks John - I hadn't considered the Swagger definitions, definitely a worthwhile feature.

Answer (score 2):

Pydantic models are useful not only for `POST` requests. It's useful for `GET` requests as well.

Using pydantic models you can implement complex input and output data validation.

Speaking about input data validation, it's most often used to validate Json data from `Body`, but you can also specify in pydantic model, that FastAPI should get attributes from `Query` or `Path` parameters.

And it's especially useful for output data validation and filtration. It`s important since it makes your API more secure and more strict (forces it to follow the API-schema).